# How can I organize polymer-element structure in order to embrace the Polymer way of developing custom elements?

Tags: javascript, html, sass, polymer

My goal has been to learn `Polymer` so I started developing a complex combo-box element.

I did my development on Plunker. Here is [**link to my plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ucRDan5GgXee0bK9NVGc).

I'm happy with my `.scss` file, but I wouldn't be opposed to some constructive criticism there. That being said what I'm mainly looking for though is your thoughts on the following three topics:

1. Am I structuring my `combo-box.html` template bindings in a bad way? If so how can I improve? I'm used to using `knockout.js` so some of my organization may come from my experience with it.
2. Currently I'm using attributes to take in settings a consumer of `combo-box` can pass to the JavaScript logic. Is this the best way to achieve a method the user of `combo-box` can decide whether they want `x` and not `y` feature?
3. Lastly I'm wondering if I could get some opinions on how I organized my code in `combo-box.js`. I started this learning experience with the idea that I didn't want any external dependencies besides `polymer.js` of course and the `platform.js` for polyfills that `polymer.js` depends on. That being said I structured my code in this basic manner:

   ```
   (function(Polymer, undefined) {

       // any global to this closure vars and functions

       // polyfill functions (this goes along with my goal of no using other libs)

       // fn that returns an object (in my mind I think of this like my model/view model

       // call into Polymer function and declaration of the element life cycle methods

   }(Polymer));
   ```

The three main points examples have been included below:

#### combo-box.html

```
<polymer-element name="combo-box">
    <template>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="combo-box.css">
        <template bind="{{ comboBox }}">
            <div class="comboBoxWrap">
                <template bind="{{ elementAttributes }}">
                    <template if="{{ leftalignedicon }}">
                        <img src="{{ leftalignedicon }}"
                            class="leftAlignedIcon"
                            alt="leftAlignedIcon">
                        <input type="text"
                            class="leftAlignedIconInput"
                            value="{{ value }}"
                            on-focus="{{ toggleOptionsVisibility }}"
                            on-blur="{{ toggleOptionsVisibility }}"
                            on-keydown="{{ optionsInputKeydown }}">
                    </template>
                    <template if="{{ rightalignedicon }}">
                        <img src="{{ rightalignedicon }}"
                            class="rightAlignedIcon"
                            alt="rightAlignedIcon">
                        <input type="text"
                            class="rightAlignedIconInput"
                            value="{{ value }}"
                            on-focus="{{ toggleOptionsVisibility }}"
                            on-blur="{{ toggleOptionsVisibility }}"
                            on-keydown="{{ optionsInputKeydown }}">
                    </template>
                    <template if="{{ !leftalignedicon && !rightalignedicon }}">
                        <input type="text"
                            on-focus="{{ toggleOptionsVisibility }}"
                            on-blur="{{ toggleOptionsVisibility }}"
                            on-keydown="{{ optionsInputKeydown }}"
                            value="{{ value }}">
                    </template>
                </template>
                <template if="{{ showOptions }}">
                    <ul>
                        <template repeat="{{ opt in options }}">
                            <li class="{{ { active: opt.active } | tokenList }}"
                                on-mousedown="{{ optionClick }}"
                                on-mouseover="{{ onHovered }}" 
                                on-mouseout="{{ onUnhovered }}">{{ opt.text }}</li>
                        </template>
                    </ul>
                </template>
            </div>
        </template>
    </template>
    <script src="comboBox.js"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

#### combo-box.js

```
(function(Polymer, undefined) {
    var pxSuffix = 'px';

    function getNodeIndex(node) {
        var index = -1;

        while ((node = node.previousSibling)) {
            if (node.nodeType != 3 || !/^\s*$/.test(node.data)) {
                index++;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    function getJSON(url, callback) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', url, true);

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4){
                if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400){
                    // Success!
                    callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
                }
                else {
                    // Error :(
                    callback(this);
                }
            }
        };

        request.send();
        request = null;
    }

    // constructor function for a new ComboBox
    function ComboBox(customElement) {
        var comboBoxModel = {
            value: '',
            options: [],
            showOptions: false,
            elementAttributes: {}
        };
        var i = 0;
        var currentAttr;
        var request;
        var historyprop = 'history';

        // take the html attributes from customElement
        // and augment them onto our comboBoxModel
        for (i; i < customElement.attributes.length; i++) {
           currentAttr = customElement.attributes[i];
           comboBoxModel.elementAttributes[currentAttr.nodeName] = currentAttr.nodeValue;
        }


        // get the data for our comboBox
        if(typeof comboBoxModel.elementAttributes.history !== 'undefined') {
            if(typeof comboBoxModel.elementAttributes.historyprop !== 'undefined') {
                historyprop = comboBoxModel.elementAttributes.historyprop;
            }
            getJSON(
                comboBoxModel.elementAttributes.history,
                function(responseObj) {
                    var iObj;
                    i = 0;
                    for (i; i < responseObj[historyprop].length; i++) {
                        iObj = responseObj[historyprop][i];
                        iObj.active = false;
                        comboBoxModel.options.push(iObj);
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        return comboBoxModel;
    }


    Polymer('combo-box', {
        created: function() {
            this.comboBox = ComboBox(this);
        },
        ready: function() {
            // I don't love this solution for icons in the input box, but this is what I got
            var shadowRoot = this.shadowRoot;
            var inputEl = shadowRoot.querySelector("input[type='text'");
            var imgEl = shadowRoot.querySelector('img');
            var imgHeight;
            var imgWidth;
            var inputHeight;
            var inputWidth;
            var heightDiffInHalf;

            if(inputEl !== null && imgEl !== null ) {
                imgHeight = imgEl.clientHeight;
                imgWidth = imgEl.clientWidth;
                inputHeight = inputEl.offsetHeight;
                inputWidth = inputEl.offsetWidth;
                heightDiffInHalf = (inputHeight - imgHeight) / 2;

                // set the img height to be the offsetTop of the input and center it within the input
                imgEl.style.top = inputEl.offsetTop + heightDiffInHalf + pxSuffix;

                // Depending on left vs right set the position of the img
                if(this.comboBox.elementAttributes.leftalignedicon || this.comboBox.elementAttributes.rightalignedicon) {
                    if(this.comboBox.elementAttributes.leftalignedicon) {
                        imgEl.style.left = inputEl.offsetLeft + pxSuffix;

                        inputEl.style.paddingLeft = imgWidth + pxSuffix;
                    }

                    if(this.comboBox.elementAttributes.rightalignedicon) {
                        imgEl.style.left = (inputEl.offsetLeft + inputWidth) + pxSuffix;
                        inputEl.style.paddingRight = imgWidth + pxSuffix;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        attributeChanged: function(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
            var _newVal = this.getAttribute(attrName);
            console.log('attributeChanged');
            console.log(attrName, 'old: ' + oldVal, 'newVal:', newVal);
            console.log('_newVal: ' + _newVal)
        },
        toggleOptionsVisibility: function(e) {
            // in the docs it says to get the model by doing:
            // var model = e.target.templateInstance.model;
            // BUT this seems to work
            // using self for setTimeout
            var self = this;

            self.comboBox.showOptions = !this.comboBox.showOptions;
        },
        optionsInputKeydown: function(e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
            var i = 0;
            var optionsLen = this.comboBox.options.length;
            var activeIndex = -1;

            // find the active option index
            for(i; i < optionsLen; i++) {
                if(this.comboBox.options[i].active === true){
                   activeIndex = i;
                   break;
                }
            }

            if(keyCode === 13) {
                // Enter
                console.log('Option chosen (Enter)... execute user defined callback');
                console.log(activeIndex);
            }
            else if(keyCode === 38) {
                // Up arrow
                if(activeIndex > 0 && activeIndex < optionsLen) {
                    this.comboBox.options[activeIndex].active = false;
                    this.comboBox.options[activeIndex - 1].active = true;
                }
                else {
                    if(activeIndex === 0) {
                        this.comboBox.options[activeIndex].active = false;
                    }
                    this.comboBox.options[optionsLen - 1].active = true;
                }
            }
            else if(keyCode === 40){
                // Down arrow
                if(activeIndex > -1 && activeIndex < (optionsLen - 1)) {
                    this.comboBox.options[activeIndex].active = false;
                    this.comboBox.options[activeIndex + 1].active = true;
                }
                else {
                    if(activeIndex === (optionsLen - 1)) {
                        this.comboBox.options[activeIndex].active = false;
                    }
                    this.comboBox.options[0].active = true;
                }
            }
        },
        onHovered: function(event, detail, sender) {
            var i = 0;
            var hoveredIndex = getNodeIndex(sender);

            for(i; i < this.comboBox.options.length; i++) {
                this.comboBox.options[i].active = false;
            }
            this.comboBox.options[hoveredIndex].active = true;
        },
        onUnhovered: function(event, detail, sender) {
            var hoveredIndex = getNodeIndex(sender);
            this.comboBox.options[hoveredIndex].active = false;
        },
        optionClick: function(event, detail, sender) {
            console.log('Option chosen (Click)... execute user defined callback');
            console.log(getNodeIndex(sender));
        }
    });


}(Polymer));
```

#### Example of use/configuration

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>combo-box</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>combo-box</h1>

        <!-- Polymer -->
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.3.4/platform.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.3.4/polymer.js"></script>

        <!-- combo-box -->
        <link rel="import" href="combo-box.html">

        <!--
        Attribute Documentation:

        history: A path/url for an ajax request to return correctly formatted JSON
        historyProp: Property name that corresponds to the array of history options
            (Optional: Defaults to 'history')
        leftAlignedIcon: Path/url for an image to use as an icon in the left side of the input box
        rightAlignedIcon: Path/url for an image to use as an icon in the right side of the input box
        -->
        <combo-box history="history.json" historyProp="myHistory" ></combo-box>
        <combo-box history="history.json"
            historyProp="myHistory"
            leftAlignedIcon="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google_jfk_icons_by_carlosjj/16/search.png">
        </combo-box>
        <combo-box history="history.json"
            historyProp="myHistory"
            rightAlignedIcon="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/snipicons/500/search-16.png">
        </combo-box>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Vogel612 Edit coming up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to let you know that

```
function getNodeIndex(node) {
    var index = -1;

    while ((node = node.previousSibling)) {
        if (node.nodeType != 3 || !/^\s*$/.test(node.data)) {
            index++;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

[Could be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9132575/7602)

```
function getNodeIndex(node) {
  return Array.prototype.indexOf.call(e.childNodes, someChildEl);
}
```

This works on any [browser that supports Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/compatibility.html).

Also this seems odd:

```
    toggleOptionsVisibility: function(e) {
        // in the docs it says to get the model by doing:
        // var model = e.target.templateInstance.model;
        // BUT this seems to work
        // using self for setTimeout
        var self = this;

        self.comboBox.showOptions = !this.comboBox.showOptions;
    },
```

Is the comment outdated? This should simply be

```
    toggleOptionsVisibility: function(e) {
        this.comboBox.showOptions = !this.comboBox.showOptions;
    },
```

There is some serious copy pastage between `// Up arrow` and `// Down arrow`

Finally,from a philosophical perspective, it seems that your code could be much leaner if combobox had an `activeIndex` property which has the index of the active item. This way you don't need to loop over the elements all the time to activate/de-activate/check activation/ check de-activation etc..

Comment: The `toggleOptionsVisibility` is in fact out of date. The first two lines of comments are there for myself to remember what the docs say, but I'm getting the same behavior using `this`. And earlier I had a `setTimeout` that did some stuff and was using `self` to be able to access the correct `this` in the `setTimeout`s scope. Thank you for the `activeIndex` idea at the model level I don't know why I didn't think of that...